quiver wind arrows are too lengthy for scale=1 and does not match the key arrow
All,
The argument scale=1 of the matplotlib quiver (wind plot) function produces lengthy arrows extending beyond the figure limits. On the other hand, using scale=None seems to yield a logical arrow length. Any insights on this?
Beside print(ax_left.scale), which must print None, yields 127.27 if only executed inside the IPython console.  Any ideas?
Lastly, given that the U=5, which should have the same constant length as the plotted arrows, 5, the length of the arrow key, surprisingly, does not match exactly the length of the wind arrows.
Thanks

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,200,9)
y = np.linspace(0,100,5)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
U = 5*np.ones_like(X)
V = 5*np.ones_like(Y)

#%% understanding "scale"
plt.close('all')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax_left=ax[0].quiver(x, y, U, V,scale=None)
ax[0].quiverkey(ax_left,X=0.8,Y=1.05,U=3.5,label='unit',labelpos='W')
ax[0].set_title('')
print('scale is '+str(ax_left.scale))

ax_right=ax[1].quiver(x, y, U, V,scale=1)
ax[0].quiverkey(ax_right,X=0.8,Y=1.05,U=3.5,label='unit',labelpos='W')
ax[1].set_title('')
print('scale is '+str(ax_right.scale))
plt.savefig('test.png')


Does this answer your question? how to use matplotlib quiver scale

I do not think so

Did you try the scale_units argument?

Not, cause I did not resize the figure. Not sure why you think it will matter here. I want to understand the results I got above using the minimal working code.

I think you'll just need to delve into this part of the quiver code https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.8.4/lib/matplotlib/quiver.py#L627.

As per the documentation under the scale_units section:

To plot vectors in the x-y plane, with u and v having the same units as x and y, use angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1.

I also adjusted the width to make the arrows look nicer.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

x = np.linspace(0, 200, 9)
y = np.linspace(0, 100, 5)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
U = 5*np.ones_like(X)
V = 5*np.ones_like(Y)

plt.close("all")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))

ax_right = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V, scale=1, scale_units="xy", angles="xy", width=4e-3)
ax.quiverkey(ax_right, X=0.8, Y=1.05, U=5, label="unit", labelpos="W")
print(f"scale is: {ax_right.scale}")

Results:

As for the key, it looks to be correct.

I tried scale_units=‘width’ and ‘height’ and it did not work, but I scale_units=‘x’ or ‘y’ or ‘xy’ did solve the problem, any idea why?  not really sure, what does it mean that u and v have the same units as x and y? what does the unit mean here?

Having the same units as X and Y means that U = 1 is 1 unit according to the x-axis and V = 1 is 1 unit according to the y-axis. So a line with U = 1 and V = 1 starting at (0, 0) will end at (1, 0). But if you didn't use the "xy" scale, then it might be longer or shorter depending on what the scale is and (I think) limits of the axes.

so should it end at (1,1), not (1,0)

Sorry, yes. I had meant to write U = 1 and V = 0, not V = 1.

Lastly, the key arrow on the top right is smaller than the plotted arrow, though both have the same unit. The arrow key is U=5, and the wind magnitude is 5. Any ideas?

The arrow in the top right is 5, but the wind magnitude is not 5, it is sqrt(5^2 + 5^2) = sqrt(50) = 7.07107... (use Pythagoras).

To have magnitude 5 for the arrows in the plot you'd need to do U = np.sqrt(0.5*25)*np.ones_like(X) (and same for V).
